# Python csv reader wrongly reading multiple rows simultaneously

Tags: python, csv

I have a simple python program reading a 'coma' delimited csv file with nearly 2000 rows. The program simply reads each line and displays it. I have manually verified each line through vi editor. When reading the csv file the program in the middle of the file somehow ignores the '\n' and reads multiple  lines simultaneously into a single row. Why is that happening? I am working on unix platform and have converted the file to unix format as well.

```
import csv
with open("fileName.csv") as f:
    reader=csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print row
```

Any clues?

thanks

Comment: If each field in your file is separated by a coma, it's going to take a hell of a long time to read it.

Comment: Time is not the issue here. Correctness is. Code snippet added.

Comment: If multiple lines are being read ignoring '\n', then it should be a data problem in the file, will not be a code issue. Please check your data.

Comment: Issue is not in your code but in your CSV file. If code would have been problem then it would have read the file wrong from the start.

Comment: Try isolating the problematic lines in your CSV file. Maybe setting `Dialect.strict` will help pinpointing the problem.

Comment: Yes, the problem seems to be with the file. Even though I converted it to unix format using ---- perl -pi -e 's/\r\n|\n|\r/\n/g' inputFile  still there seems to be a problem with detecting \n on some lines. Why should that be happening? The file seems to be fine when opened in vi

Comment: The Python csv reader is able to deal with all kinds of line endings, there is no need to convert it.

Comment: Is your input file using quoting? Is there a field with a quote that is not closed until somewhere on a subsequent line. Should be pretty easy to locate the first line that causes the problem and then add it, the preceding line, and the next line to your question.

Comment: @mhawke You were right. There were quotes in there. Thanks a lot for your help.